Solana contact not found
I applied for Solana miner.one site for upgrade my plans  yesterday and I spend 0.49 of Solana through bitget wallet but I didn't receive any updates for upgrade

The https://www.solminer.one seems to be a scam, e.g., see review https://www.trustpilot.com/review/www.solminer.one.
From a technical perspective, there is no mining at Solana so it is hard to be offered.
It's good to know that Solana does not "do" mining as it's a proof-of-stake (PoS) chain where it's used term "validation", see https://cryptoadventure.com/a-beginners-guide-to-crypto-mining-vs-validating/.
